# Python: nmap.PortScanner() Path error

Tags: python3, pycharm

So as I imported python-nmap library to my interpreter:

```
import nmap
nm = nmap.PortScanner()
```

nmap.PortScanner() somehow shows me the following error. The installed python-nmap is 0.6.1 version, but the following error shows

> File "
>   ...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\nmap\nmap.py",
>   line 131, in **init**
>       os.getenv('PATH')

I'm working with python v3.7 although I installed nmap package + python-nmap.

> File "...\networkScanner.py", line 78, in 
>       nmapScanner(subnets, csvfolder)   File "...\networkScanner.py", line 21, in nmapScanner
>       nm = nmap.PortScanner()  # instantiate nmap.PortScanner object